How to use bind parameters in Joomla query using simple SQL string
Is there a way of binding query parameters in a Joomla database query when using a plain string for the SQL statement (rather than the methods like ->select, ->where, etc.)?
For example, if I have the following query:
$db = Factory::getContainer()->get('DatabaseDriver');
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query = "SELECT value from #__fields_values
            WHERE field_id = 3
            AND item_id = :article_id";

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();

How do I bind the parameter value to the parameter? If I use
$query->bind(':article_id', $article_id);
before the second-last line I get an error because the variable $query is understood as a string, whereas "->bind" needs an object.
In case anyone is wondering why I don't just use the methods like ->select, ->where, etc., my reasons are:

The sql string is much easier to read and write.
I can construct and test the sql string in a MySQL database manager like Navicat and then copy-paste it directly into my PHP code in my Joomla installation.
I am writing code for my own use, not for an extension that will be distributed and used on machines with parameters that I know nothing about. So I know that I am working with MariaDB or MySQL and don't have to make provision for other database systems.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Get the newly set query from the database and work with it:
$db->setQuery($query)->getQuery()->bind(':article_id', $id);

There is also Joomla\Database\DatabaseQuery::setQuery() method which allows setting custom SQL string directly on the query object. Sadly, this method is not present on Joomla\Database\QueryInterface interface so it may not be safe to use.
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->setQuery("SELECT value from #__fields_values
        WHERE field_id = 3
        AND item_id = :article_id")
    ->bind(':article_id', $id);

$db->setQuery($query);

